# How to take screenshot in python during the code

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, screenshot

i maked a while loop, that when i am pressed the key on my keyboard it takes me a screenshot.but i noticed that the screenshot takes only when i exit the code, i want that the screenshot takes during the code.
here is the code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab
import keyboard
import sys

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("i"):
        img = ImageGrab.grab()
        img.save("screenshot.png")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("e"):
        sys.exit(0)
```

i tried to do another python script that takes screenshot and in the main script i open it.but it also didnt work.

Comment: Does pressing a key actually notify your program immediately? E.g. does your program exit immediately when you press "e"?

Comment: So when you press the key 'i' the program will take several million screenshots until you release it,  since you have it inside a loop

Comment: @alexis yes it exit when i pressing "e".

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki. i know it. but i asked diffrent question

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using keyboard.on_press_key instead of a loop. This way you wait for events to happen, instead of spending processing power constantly running in a loop.

keyboard.on_press_key takes the first argument as a ASCII value of a key. I passed this in by calling the ord() function on the corresponding letter. The second argument is the function that will get called when the letter is pressed.

Instead of mapping the letter 'e' to its own exit function. I recommend using keyboard.wait to keep listening for events instead of the loop. The first argument is the key that keyboard.wait will listen for. Once the script is done, the program will exit automatically.

```
import keyboard
from PIL import ImageGrab

def screenshot():
    """ Take a screenshot and save it """
    img = ImageGrab.grab()
    img.save("screenshot.png")

# When the key 'i' is pressed, calls the screenshot function
keyboard.on_press_key(ord('i'), screenshot)

# Process key events until the key 'e' is pressed
keyboard.wait(ord('e'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This way the `take_screenshot` function runs in the background, and the main thread can continue to check for key presses and execute other code.

```
def take_screenshot():
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("i"):
            img = ImageGrab.grab()
            img.save("screenshot.png")

screenshot_thread = threading.Thread(target=take_screenshot)
screenshot_thread.start()

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("e"):
        sys.exit(0)
```